# Google sheets date reformatting when inserting new row using ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: date, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a Google sheet with a column of dates that look like this.

```
22/04/2020 09:01:24
22/04/2020 09:05:54
22/04/2020 09:17:06
22/04/2020 10:04:48
22/04/2020 21:05:26
```

These dates need to be formatted `YYYY-MM-DDD` in order to be imported correctly into another system. So I decided to add another column, find the date fragment and create a valid date. This function is.

`=MID(A1,7,4)&"-"&MID(A1,4,2)&"-"&MID(A1,1,2)`

This results in the correct date format e.g. `2020-04-16`

Now, another process which adds rows to this spreadsheet, when this happens the formula is not copied to newly created cell. I read about `ARRAYFORMULA` so in the first row I added the following.

`=ARRAYFORMULA({"Submitted at";IF(ROW(A2:A),MID(W2,7,4)&"-"&MID(W2,4,2)&"-"&MID(W2,1,2),"")})`

Although this solved one problem of the formula not being copied, it now only shows the first date for every row e.g.

```
2020-04-16
2020-04-16
2020-04-16
2020-04-16
2020-04-16
2020-04-16
```

I think this might be something to do with relative cell references? I am a bit stuck at what to do next or even what the problem might be. I would appreciate some understanding of where I'm going wrong (or a simpler solution for reformatting dates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change those W2s to W2:W

you also might try this simpler formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Submitted at";IF(W2:W="",,TEXT(W2:W,"yyyy-mm-dd"))})
```

Comment: @Tom You're welcome.  Hopefully you didn't spend too long on it before coming for help :)